# How to plot the significant Tukey results as red

Tags: r, data-visualization, anova, tukey

I have used the following code to plot the results of the Tukey test after my Anova analysis in R.

```r
TukeyHSD(myANOVA, conf.level=.90)
TUKEY <- TukeyHSD(myANOVA, conf.level=.90)
plot(TUKEY , las=1 , col="black")
```

However, since the number of lines plotted is too large, I would like to have the significant ones highlighted or in red. I have seen [a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68415342/how-to-highlight-significant-results-in-tukey-test) with the comment "overwrite the black lines showing significant differences with red lines" however, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: It would also help to post a link to the "similar question" you refer to in your answer ...

Comment: looks like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68415342/how-to-highlight-significant-results-in-tukey-test

Comment: I posted a solution there. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68415342/how-to-highlight-significant-results-in-tukey-test/72059339#72059339

Answer (score 1):

Imagine we have the following data:

```
data <- data.frame(group = rep(c("P1", "P2", "P3"), each = 40), values = c(rnorm(40, 0, 3),rnorm (40, 8, 10),rnorm (40, 0, 3)))
```

Then we conduct a Tukey test, convert the results to a matrix, and then to a dataframe (I don't know how to do it otherwise):

```
results_test <- TukeyHSD(aov(data$values~ data$group), conf.level=.95)
results_matrix <- as.matrix (results_test) 
df_res <- as.data.frame(results_matrix[1])
```

Then we plot it using an `ifelse` function, as a function of the p-values:

```
plot(results_matrix, col= ifelse(df_res[,4]<0.05, 'red', 'black'))
```

Comment: nice and simple, although it does some weird things to the tick marks and indicator lines as well (because `col` is passed through `...` to some places where it's not wanted).

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer the plot generated by the **multcomp** package, and with this package you can perform the Tukey test for unbalanced designs.

```
library(multcomp)

### set up a one-way ANOVA
data(warpbreaks)
amod <- aov(breaks ~ tension, data = warpbreaks)
### specify all pair-wise comparisons among levels of variable "tension"
tuk <- glht(amod, linfct = mcp(tension = "Tukey"))
### p-values
pvalues <- adjusted()(tuk)$pvalues
### get confidence intervals
ci.glht <- confint(tuk)
### plot them
plot(ci.glht, col = ifelse(pvalues < 0.05, "red", "black"), 
     xlab = "Difference in mean levels")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, Stéphane. I was able to plot the graph with the red lines. However, even though I changed the p values in the plotting formula to 0.1 (because I need a 90% conf. level) the plot was still displaying  "95% family-wise confidence level". Is there any further step I have to do to have it 90%? Thank you.☺

Comment: @JulianaN Probably **confint(tuk, level = 0.9)**.

Comment: I was able to plot the graph with a 90% confidence level after all. I was adding the referred confint in the wrong place. It worked after I addedit here: ### get confidence intervals
`ci.glht <- confint(tuk2, level=0.9)`